# How to turn one 10GB zip file into five 2GB files using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var archiver = require('archiver');
var output = fs.createWriteStream('./test.zip');
var archive = archiver('zip', {
    gzip: true,
    zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
});

archive.on('error', function(err) {
  throw err;
});

// pipe archive data to the output file
archive.pipe(output);

// append files
archive.file('troll.mkv', {name: 'troll.mkv'});
// wait for streams to complete
archive.finalize();
```

I have already figured out how to archive the file. I need to know how to turn a large file into several small files

I would like to do this using the archiver library.

Comment: This might help -> https://github.com/dannycho7/split-file-stream

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a zip file? Using archiver

Comment: Not sure what you mean, archiver has no concept of splitting files, its the reason you supply a stream ->   `output = fs.createWriteStream`,  so instead of using that, use `split-file-stream` instead.  IOW, your still using archiver but just controlling how the files are written to disk.

Comment: @Dekillston What are you going to do with the small files? Are they supposed to be usable on their own somehow? What are you trying to gain?

Comment: @Bergi   Zip splitting is a common practice, not done so much these days.  But you might want to do it because the file-system has a maximum file size.  Maybe your uploading to server that limits individual file size.  Or maybe downloading reasons, a lost connection for download on 2Gig is better than 10Gig..  There not usable on there own so all of them are required, but most Zip managers should be able to auto-stitch them with the correct file naming.

Answer (score 2):

To split a zip file into multiple files you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/split-file-stream

You basically replace your `var output = fs.createWriteStream('./test.zip');` , also remove `archive.pipe(output);`  as `split-file-stream` will be doing this for you.

Below is a working sample, to keep things simple I've reduced the split size to 100, and it basically compresses and splits it's own source for demonstration purposes.

Note: This will create compatible Zip splits, notice the naming `output.zip.001`, `output.zip.002` this is a standard that allows most Zip archives to auto stitch for unzipping.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var splitFileStream = require("split-file-stream");
var archiver = require('archiver');


//var output = fs.createWriteStream('./test.zip');

var customSplit = splitFileStream.getSplitWithGenFilePath(
    (n) => `./output.zip.${(n + 1).toString().padStart(3, '0')}`)

var archive = archiver('zip', {
    gzip: true,
    zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.    
});



customSplit(archive, 100, (error, filePaths) => {
    /* If an error occured, filePaths will still contain all files that were written */
    if (error) throw error; // Alternatively you could just log the error instead of throwing: if (error) console.error(error)

    console.log("This is an array of my new files:", filePaths);
    /* stream will be saved to files in the path ∈ { ./outputFiles.split-x | x ∈ N } */
});

archive.on('error', function (err) {
    throw err;
});

// pipe archive data to the output file
//archive.pipe(output);

// append files
archive.file('./index.js', { name: 'index.js' });
// wait for streams to complete
archive.finalize();
```

Comment: Thanks, everything works, can you tell me how to assemble it? I read github, it says how to do this, but the program did not build it correctly. File does not open!

Comment: @Dekillston  What did you read on github?, I'm not sure what your trying to do here.  Are you uploading 10Gig to github, not sure that is even possible, there is Git LFS, but from what I can gather that just acts like a pointer to these big files.